# Choosing 8 cards from a deck of cards where all cards have a value between 1 and 8

Tags: proof-verification, combinations

Using combinations, how can I show the amount of ways possible choosing 8 cards from a deck of cards where all cards have a value between ace and 8 (including ace and 8)?

My current solution is: C(13,8) x C(4,4) x C(52,8) / C(52/8) 
where C(13,8) represents the amount of cards per suit, C(4,4) represents the amount of suits and C(52,8) represents the total amount of cards.

Am I approaching this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of cards in the deck between $1$ (ace) and $8$ inclusive is $8{\,\cdot\,}4 =32$.

So the number of qualifying draws is just $\binom{32}{8}$.

The probability of getting a qualifying draw is
$$\frac{\binom{32}{8}}{\binom{52}{8}}$$

Comment: Thanks so much for your help quasi!